# merge to dataframes on first part of a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['XYZ', 'ABC1', 'CDS'], 'col1':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['XYZ1', 'XYZ2', 'ABC1', 'ABC11', 'CDSS', 'CDS', 'ABC2', 'ABC', 'XYA'], 
                    'col2':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
```

```
    id   col1
0   XYZ     1
1   ABC1    2
2   CDS     3
```

and

```
    id   col2
0   XYZ1    1
1   XYZ2    2
2   ABC1    3
3   ABC11   4
4   CDSS    5
5   CDS     6
6   ABC2    7
7   ABC     8
8   XYA     9
```

and I would like to merge df1 to df2 on the full id of df1 and the first characters of df2 that match it, such that I get this dataframe

```
      id col2  col1
0   XYZ1    1   1.0
1   XYZ2    2   1.0
2   ABC1    3   2.0
3   ABC11   4   2.0
4   CDSS    5   3.0
5   CDS     6   3.0
6   ABC2    7   NaN
7   ABC     8   NaN
8   XYA     9   NaN
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to merge the two columns but you'll need to add a custom column for `df2` first based on if the id in `df2` is a substring for the id in `df1`:

```
ids1 = df1.id.to_list()
def id_subset(id, ids1):
  for s in ids1:
    if s in id:
      return s
  return False
# add a new substring id column
df2['id2'] = df2['id'].apply(lambda x: id_subset(x, ids1) )

# merge and clean
df_out = df2.merge(df1, left_on = 'id2', right_on = 'id', how='left')
df_out.rename(columns={'id_x':'id'}).drop(columns=['id_y', 'id2'])
```

Output:

```
      id  col2  col1
0   XYZ1     1   1.0
1   XYZ2     2   1.0
2   ABC1     3   2.0
3  ABC11     4   2.0
4   CDSS     5   3.0
5    CDS     6   3.0
6   ABC2     7   NaN
7    ABC     8   NaN
8    XYA     9   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply `df1` as a mapping used in [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
id_map = df1.set_index('id')['col1'].to_dict()
new_df = (df2.assign(col1=df2['id'].map(lambda x:
                                        next((v for k, v in id_map.items()
                                              if x.startswith(k)), None))))
print(new_df)
```

---

```
      id  col2  col1
0   XYZ1     1   1.0
1   XYZ2     2   1.0
2   ABC1     3   2.0
3  ABC11     4   2.0
4   CDSS     5   3.0
5    CDS     6   3.0
6   ABC2     7   NaN
7    ABC     8   NaN
8    XYA     9   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the keys from ids in `df2` which starts with ids from `df1` then use these keys to perform `merge` operation

```
df2['key'] = df2['id'].str.extract(r'^(%s)' % '|'.join(df1['id']))
result = df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'id': 'key'}), on='key', how='left')
```

---

```
      id  col2   key  col1
0   XYZ1     1   XYZ   1.0
1   XYZ2     2   XYZ   1.0
2   ABC1     3  ABC1   2.0
3  ABC11     4  ABC1   2.0
4   CDSS     5   CDS   3.0
5    CDS     6   CDS   3.0
6   ABC2     7   NaN   NaN
7    ABC     8   NaN   NaN
8    XYA     9   NaN   NaN
```